# React Native. OneSignal. No profiles for 'com.myapp.ios.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' were found

Tags: xcode, react-native, onesignal

I have followed OneSignal's [setup instructions](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) for React Native, but 
When I try to upload app to TestFlight I get the following error '**No profiles for 'com.myapp.ios.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' were found**'

[image]

My **XCode** is 10.0.
Anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you found any solution for it, i am also getting same issue.

Comment: how did you solve this?!

Answer (score 2):

Below instructions assume that your app is building and you have successfully deployed TestFlight builds in the past (since that is where I started from). I had to use the below as "Automatically manage signing" resulted in a build fail in Xcode 10:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile
2. Click "+' to create a new provisioning profile
3. Choose the type of provisioning profile you want (I went with App Store since I use TestFlight builds to test)
4. for App ID choose "XC YOUR_DOMAIN_APP_ID OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" and make sure enable the App Groups capability
5. after you have downloaded the provisioning profile, go into Xcode, turn off automatically signing on the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension target in General tab and import the provisioning profile you just downloaded.
6. Use Product > Archive as usual to create your ipa file for App Store upload as usual

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue. I recommend to create Dev and Production ones

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error on appcenter. You can temporarily workaround this problem if you create a new provision file for the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension identifier and sign your OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension with this provision. 
(Your app provision should be different. your app -> com.app.example)